# Change the color of the input button when writing a letter?

Tags: javascript, html

With this code when writing a character or letter in the search field, a div will open (Hello World!). But if the first character is an asterisk, the div disappears. Now, there are two search buttons, one red and one blue, and what I need is that when writing the first character or letter (as long as it is not an asterisk) at the same time the blue search button appears covering or replacing the button red (the blue button must initially be hidden).

See in: https://jsfiddle.net/qhxysu1o/1/

```js
$('#search').on('input', function(event) {
  $('#hello').show();    
  if(!event.target.value.trim() || event.originalEvent.charCode === 42 || event.target.value.startsWith("*")) {
    $('#hello').hide();
    $(this).css({color: 'green'});
  } else {
    $('#hello').show();  
    $(this).css({color: ''});
  }
});
```

```css
#hello {
  display:none;
}
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {

  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;

}
  .searchButton4 {
              position: relative;
     font-weight:normal;
       border-top-right-radius: 22px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 22px;
         border-top-left-radius: 22px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 22px;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 130px;
    width: 38px;
  height: 39px;
 border: 0px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left:13px;
  top:0px;
    right:5px;
    outline: none;
      background: #d9534f;
}
.searchButton4:hover {
  background: #c34a47;
  }
.searchButton4_2 {
  position: relative;
     font-weight:normal;
       border-top-right-radius: 22px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 22px;
         border-top-left-radius: 22px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 22px;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 130px;
    width: 38px;
  height: 39px;
 border: 0px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left:13px;
  top:0px;
    right:5px;
    outline: none;
      background: #02acdb;
      margin-left:-20px;
}
.searchButton4_2:hover {
  background: #0094bd;
  } 

}
```

```html
<input id="search" autocomplete="on"/>
<div id="hello" >Hello World!</div>

<button type="submit" class="searchButton4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Jogar BetCode"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lg"></i>Search</button>

<button type="submit" id="hello2" class="searchButton4_2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Jogar BetCode"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lg"></i>Search</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placement of hello world div changed. 
https://jsfiddle.net/b08uhkz3/

```html
<input id="search" autocomplete="on"/>


<button type="submit" class="searchButton4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Jogar BetCode" id="hello1"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lg"></i>Search</button>

<button type="submit" id="hello2" class="searchButton4_2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Jogar BetCode"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lg"></i>Search</button>
<div id="hello" >Hello World!</div>
```

```js
$('#search').on('input', function(event) {
  $('#hello').show();    
  if(!event.target.value.trim() || event.originalEvent.charCode === 42 || event.target.value.startsWith("*")) {
    $('#hello').hide();
    $("#hello1").show();
    $("#hello2").hide();
    $(this).css({color: 'green'});
  } else {
    $('#hello').show();  
     $("#hello1").hide();
    $("#hello2").show();
    $(this).css({color: ''});
  }
});
```

This css added.

```css
.searchButton4_2 {
left:29px;
}
```